# Adobe Indesign automatic deletion of overflow text

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

Indesign CS5.5 (v7.5.2)

Is there an automated method to simply remove all overset text in a text frame?

I don't want it hidden by a smaller frame. I want it gone.

I spend so much time simply removing pages of overset text it would be helpful if there was a command such as "Remove overset text" or "Truncate text from here".

Thanks!

Comment: So, to be specific. You are removing lots of ovetset text ( pages worth of text ), not actual pages?

Comment: I'm curious why you have *pages* of overset. Can something be done with your source file? Is there a different way for you to flow copy into InDesign?

Comment: Yes text, not pages. I could adjust workflow by opening a Word file and deleting text there before import into Indesign, but that's no easier than just removing text in Indesign.

Comment: So what are you typesetting that you need individual, unlinked text boxes with only N words and you have to delete the rest repeatedly?

Comment: So what happens to the deleted text? If it's just trashed, then it seems like you would end up with a lot of half-finished sentences/paragraphs/articles. Seems like if a piece of writing needs to be edited down, that ought to be the job of the editor and writer. In most cases, you can't just randomly chop off the last X words in a piece of writing and still have an acceptable product.

Comment: I'm not concerned or trying to educate you. I'm just trying to understand what kind of workflow would create a need for this sort of content trimming without creating those problems. I assumed that I'm simply missing part of the equation, hence my question. I didn't think it'd be such a touchy subject.

Comment: Fair enough. I was just curious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shortest way to handle this without a custom script is to go to the end of the last "real" text frame, then use <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, which selects all text past the cursor, followed by <kbd>Delete / Backspace</kbd>. If you have Smart Reflow turned on, this will automatically delete any extra pages and their frames, if you have them.

Given your description of the workflow, you might find vjoon's [Overset Manager](http://www.vjoon.com/products/vjoon-overset-manager/) or DTP Tools' [TextCount](http://www.dtptools.com/product.asp?id=tcin&more=features) useful additions to the workflow. Both companies and he amazing [Rorohiko](http://www.rorohiko.com/) have numerous InDesign Scripts that are very useful enhancements for handling long text.

Comment: You're entirely welcome! Actually, on thinking it over, even a custom script mapped to a keyboard shortcut would really only save you a couple of keystrokes. Might be worth it if you're doing this 20+ times a day, but probably not otherwise. I have Find/Change by List mapped to a kbsc, because on some book projects I *do* use it 20+ times a day. :P

Comment: Thanks! [click in box] > `end` > `cmd+shift+end` > `delete` just saved me several hours.

Comment: Alt Shift End if you're on a Mac

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the command you're looking for exists. You might find this solution workable though.

1. Place your cursor at the end of the text you want to keep.
2. Hit <kbd>Cmd / Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. The story editor opens with its cursor in the same place.
3. Click/drag the cursor to select the rest of the copy (it's much faster this way).
4. <kbd>Delete / Backspace</kbd>.
5. Hit <kbd>Cmd / Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> again, you're back in layout view.

Comment: Story editor is helpful. For the most part that's what I use. Unfortunately, I just dislike having to continually delete text which is overset. I guess there's no automated method. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize. PageMaker, in the old days, did what you want, if I remember correctly. Then came InDesign. I had a hard time with it, wanted to do just what you describe. I don't know any other way. Suggest it to Adobe! :)

Comment: Yeah I remember Pagemaker having such a command. Which is why I was hoping I was just missing it in Indd... guess not :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can, hold down

shift, command, fn and the down pointing arrow key.

This selects all remaining content, then hit delete.

'fn' is the equivalent of the 'end' key.